# List of integers has nonetype even after filter

Tags: python

I am having some trouble to use the map function in python, as it seems i am multiplying by NoneType, although it shouldn't be as far as i know. Thisis a implementation of gaussian blur that i am trying to optimize, even knowing that i could use numpy or opencv implementations the assignement asks that i try to do my own (and i may need to do an arbitrary dimension blur later...).

img_ is a list of lists converted from NumPy (img.tolist) and weights is a numpy.ndarray of doubles, both of size v-u.

The following is my code:

```
A = []
if(u<0):
   A = img_[i][u:-1] + img_[i][0:v]
else:
   A = img_[i][u:v]
matrix[i][j] = reduce(operator.add, map(operator.mul,weights,A))
```

This is the exception i receive:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 152, in <module>
    channels.append(GBlur(c,3,2))
  File "test.py", line 68, in GBlur
    matrix[i][j] = reduce(operator.add, map(operator.mul,weights,filter(None,A)))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'float' and 'NoneType'
```

And a test i did to see if i was doing anything wrong:

```
Result of print(map(type,A)) : [<type 'int'>, <type 'int'>, <type 'int'>, <type 'int'>, <type 'int'>, <type 'int'>]
```

Any ideas of what i could be doing wrong?

Comment: There must be a None value in `weights`

Comment: What is `type(A)`? You initialize `A` with `[]`, but then you throw it away in line 3 or 5, that's at least odd. Might also help if you showed `A` and `weights`. They're small enough to post, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that

```
filter(None, A)
```

returns a list wich has less elements than "weights"

You can reproduce the error with this in the interactive console

```
>>> map(operator.mul,[1,2,3,4],filter(None,[1,2,None,4]))
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

You should, for example, replace Nones with other numbers. You can use list comprehension for that. For example, if you want to replace Nones with zeros, you can

```
matrix[i][j] = reduce(operator.add, map(operator.mul, weights, [x if x else 0 for x in A]))
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped me find the problem!
At the end of the image i was picking one element less and that was the problem...